# Calling boolean methods

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, compiler-errors

My overall goal with this program is to validate that a user inputted string is in fact a valid number. I am required to use at least two methods, including the main method. I have read many posts related to calling user-defined methods from within the main method, but I am however struggling to make mine work. When declaring my isAValidNumber method, I keep getting the error "illegal start of expression". How can I declare this method so that I can call it from within the main method and contentiously run it until the user enters an invalid invalid number?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsAValidNumber
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //prompt user for a valid number
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter a valid integer or floating point value: \n");

        String input = consoleInput.nextLine(); 


        /* while(isAValidNumber = true)
        {
            //
        } */

        public static isAValidNumber(String input)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<input.length();j++)
            {
                if(input.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+") == true)
                {
                    boolean isAValidNumber = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean isAValidNumber = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move it to outside main.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use Integer.parseInt(String s) API available in java.lang.Integer

Comment: I spent over an hour trying to figure out how, so I just assume go with what little I know about regex matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare methods inside of methods in Java. Declare `isAValidNumber` outside of `main` (either before or after it, doesn't matter) and you should be OK:

```
public class IsAValidNumber
{   
    public static boolean isAValidNumber(String input)
    {
        // Method's body snippet for brevity's sake
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Code that can call isAValidNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some return type to isValidNumber? ;)

Comment: Nice catch @Rc `-)

Comment: is boolean not the return type?

Comment: @Chaos it is, but my initial post was missing it. The later [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46628592/revisions) fixed that careless omission.